# Android : 3 elements side by side

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know how to align 3 elements side by side. I would like to have :

- One view with a thin width on the left
- One linearLayout with text content on the middle
- One imageView always on the right

Like this :

[image]

And today, i got this :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gris_clair"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/blanc" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="7dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@color/green_normal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/test2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you are trying to get depends on the content like the length of text and size of image in such layout there is no such thing like one size fits all data

Comment: You just add `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `TextView` `LinearLayout` and see the _MAGIC_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your layout by setting the root LinearLayout to a horizontal orientation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gris_clair"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green_normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You may want to tweak the colors or sizes to fit your desired end result.
I set the parent View's height to wrap the content, first two Views to match the parent view's height and the image to your size. This means that your image will decide the parent View's height.

If you want to evenly space/scale the views horizontally on your screen and use up all the space they have available you should look at the `android:layout_weight` attribute. You would set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for each View you want to scale with screen size and add `android:layout_weight="x"` where x is a number.

The number you choose will depend on how you want to divide up the available space each View will use. As an example if you wanted one View to use 1/3rd of the available space with a second using 2/3rds then set the first to `1` and the second to `2`. `1+2=3` so `1 of a total 3 units` and `2 of a total 3 units`.

Answer (score 2):

For your textview use weight to fill up space:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) for that. and for the image view add alignparentright rule.

```
<RelativeLayout >

    <View />

    <LinearLayout/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

or use the weight for linearlayout, put 1 for textview and rest 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy solve this problem using weight in LinearLayout, or make your parent RelativeLayout and place middle layout toLeftOf your left view and toRightOf your right view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative Layout instead of linear layout to design custom design of your page.
It might help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gris_clair"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/blanc" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/green_normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

check this it might help you